# In linux task scheduler, where does the sheduler_tick() called?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, scheduling

Recently I am playing with the linux task scheduler.

Now I wan to find out the load balancing mechanism of the task scheduler and CFS algorithm. First, I have found in the `__schedule()` function `idle_balance(cpu, rq)` is called which try to do some load balancing if the current runqueue is empty.

Then I also found in the `core.c` file there is a function `scheduler_tick()` which seems to be called periodically, update rq and other data structures and also do the load balancing ( calling function `trigger_load_balance(rq, cpu)`). Am I right? But how does the `scheduler_tick()` work? Where is the timer? I know the CFS not tick-based.So probably there is a timer created after the boot which will call `scheduler_tick()` periodically?

This seems to be a naive question but I am a rookie to the linux system now.

Comment: `scheduler_tick()` is probably just tied to timer IRQ handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fired by an interrupt request generated at intervals by the system timer. [1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=414983&seqNum=2)

Comment: So I think my understanding was right.The system clock is created during the boot. Thx,

Comment: The system clock is created during the fabrication of the motherboard in a factory :-)